# Derivative between two smooth manifolds is well defined

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a (non-English) book in Differential Geometry. The author has introduce this mapping: $T_x f : T_x M \to T_{f(x)} N$ by $T_x f ([\alpha]_x) = [f \circ \alpha]_{f(x)}$ where $[\alpha]_x$ is the equivalence class of smooth curves $\alpha : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ passing through x. And $f : M \to N$ is a smooth map between the two smooth manifolds.

My question is how this can be a well defined map? That is how $\alpha \sim \beta$ (which by definition equals $\lim_t \dfrac{\| \phi \circ \alpha (t) - \phi \circ \beta (t)\|}{t} =0$ for some $(U, \phi)$) implies $f \circ \alpha \sim f \circ \beta$?

I believe such things require detailed proof but the book considers it a trivial/immediate fact!

My first thought is to show that $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\| \phi \circ \alpha (t) - \phi \circ \beta (t)\|}{t} =0$ implies that $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\| \phi \circ f \circ \alpha (t) - \phi \circ f \circ \beta (t)\|}{t} =0$. Though it is based on the definition, but a comment below says that it is incorrect!

Comment: I removed $ when I wanted to write a ~ b because there was no way to latex it!

Comment: I've edited the ~s in for you; the code is `\sim`, as in `a\sim b`$a\sim b$. I guess "sim" is short for "similar" (that's how I remember it, anyway)

Comment: Can you give the name of the book? Also, it seems your definition of $\alpha\sim \beta$ is wrong. Perhaps it should be $ \|\phi\circ \alpha(t) - \phi\circ \beta(t)\|/t\to 0$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor, thanks for editing. The book is in Persian (lecture notes). If you read Persian I email it to you?

Comment: I don't read Persian, sorry :) :) but if you put the name in the question, other people can find this question by searching for the book name. This is why I suggested it

Comment: If (V,ψ) is a chart at f(x) then ψ∘f∘ϕ−1 is a differentiable map from one Euclidean neighborhood to another Euclidean neighborhood.

Comment: I would recommend that you write down explicitly what you *need* to show and then see if @blamocur's comment about $\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$ might be helpful.

Comment: Did you already learn vector calculus or not yet? If you did, then you should be able to use the theorem about the derivative of the difference of two vector-functions to rewrite the "equivalence" condition in a more recognizable form. Also, think about the Calculus Chain Rule.

Comment: @MoisheKohan chain rule I can apply for limit when one function is present and limit is not taken on two functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited it.

Comment: Concerning your last sentence. No, you are not asked to show $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\| \phi \circ f \circ \alpha (t) - \phi \circ f \circ \beta (t)\|}{t} =0$. Indeed $\phi$ is a chrat on $M$ and $f\circ \alpha$, $f\circ \beta$ are curves on $N$, so the term $\phi \circ f \circ \alpha $ and $\phi \circ f \circ \beta$ dont make sense.

Comment: @ArcticChar but that follows from the definition?

Comment: Can you write down the definition of $\phi$? What is the domain?

Comment: What you wrote is based on a **faulty application** of the correct definition. What you should have done is: Introduce a notation $(\phi,U)$ for a chart in $M$ ($x\in U$) and $(\psi,V)$ for a chart in $N$ ($f(x)\in V$) and then wrote the last limit using the composition $\psi\circ f\circ \alpha$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion: At first, forget about charts and assume that $M$ and $N$ are open subsets in ${\mathbb R}^m$ and ${\mathbb R}^n$ respectively. Then the notion of equivalence between smooth curves $\alpha, \beta$ (in $M$) at $x=\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$ that your book uses reads:
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\alpha(t)-\beta(t)}{t}=0 \iff 
 \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\alpha(t)-x - \beta(t)+x}{t}=0
$$
Using the definition of the derivative (and the limit rule that informally reads "limit of the difference is the difference of limits") , this condition is equivalent to
$$
\alpha'(0)-\beta'(0)=0 \iff \alpha'(0)=\beta'(0).  
$$
The same interpretation, of course, applies to the paths $\tilde\alpha=f\circ \alpha, \tilde\beta=f\circ \beta$. Now, your task is to show:
$$
\alpha'(0)=\beta'(0) \Rightarrow \tilde\alpha'(0)= \tilde\beta'(0). 
$$
If you know the Chain Rule in multivariable calculus, you should be able to establish this implication easily. This would mean that for $x=\alpha(0)=\beta(0)$, $y=\tilde\alpha(0)=\tilde\beta(0)$,
$$
[\alpha]_x= [\beta]_x \Rightarrow [\tilde\alpha]_y= [\tilde\beta]_y,
$$
as required. Once you are done with this part, you should think about the charts on general manifolds and how the above observation implies the desired conclusion in general.